# Supporting layers in a cocoa graphics app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, calayer

I want to create a small desktop graphics app in cocoa that allows the user to add layers. In Apple's docs there is plenty of information on layers in the context of animation, but no mention of how to implement layer's of the kind you get in apps like Gimp or Photoshop. Is `CALayer` design to be used in this way, or do I need to roll my own 'static layer' api?

Comment: My guess is that you can. One would have a button in the UI for adding a layer to the view. Then underneath the hood the custom view would have something like [[self layer] addSublayer:sublayer] (for a layer-backed or layer-hosting view, either)...

Answer (score 0):

CALayer has nothing to do with the way graphics apps implement their layers except of the concept of layering things.

Check out the source from Pixen on Github to see one way to approach this kind of thing.

You could use CALayers, but you could just as easily use any NSView.

You definitely want to know more about Core Graphics / Quartz and the graphics context and composite rendering.

It's all about creating a table view, where each row represents a layer.
Then the main document view is actually compositing the contents of those layers, based on the configuration defined in the UI.